# ValidateInput Attribute with Exclude feature on .NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, attributes

Good day!

Now in ValidateInput Attribute there is no Exclude option (it was in latest versions of MVC3, if i'm right in RC), that we really need  to have.

The question is how to make Custom Validate Input Attribute, that provide the functionality of excluding some properties of model from Validation.

PS> We know about [AllowHtml] and this is not working for us regarding some singularity of our system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Bind in the controller..

```
public ActionResult Test([Bind(Include="Name,Age")]MyClass myClass)
```

Comment: or Exclude, but I prefer specifying the things I want, and not the things I dont want, else it might be a problem when you add things to it.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this will not work for us, cause bind just include the item to be passed to view, and we need to exclude properties from checking, but pass them to view

Comment: In that case I think you need to pass an "EditModel", where you specify which properties are needed. And, ofc, making sure that the other properties are allowed to be null in database.

Comment: See this for info: http://www.em64t.net/2011/01/organizing-view-models-in-asp-net-mvc-part-1-of-3/

Comment: part 3 seems to be missing link: http://www.em64t.net/2011/03/organizing-view-models-in-asp-net-mvc-part-3-of-3/